# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Trend and Intercept

Tags: time-series, econometrics, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, eviews

I am trying to determine if I should include an "intercept" or a "trend and intercept" when using the Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test.  I ran a regression with my dependent variable and a time trend and both the intercept and trend were statistically significant.  Is this statistical significance what determines if I should include a "trend and intercept" in the ADF test?  My data is unstructured/undated.  The series contains 252 observations and there are about 6 observations per year from 1970-2014.  Below are my regression results and a graph of the raw data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out existing posts on Dickey-Fuller test? See, for example, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44647/which-dickey-fuller-test-should-i-apply-to-a-time-series-with-an-underlying-mode) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/trend-or-no-trend).

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tseries)
library(urca)
data2<-na.remove(data1$SANDP) #assumed one dataset
    data2
    c<-adf.test(data2,k=2)
    c
    summary(c$statistic)
```

useful command for you

```
summary(ur.df(data2,type=c("drift"),lags=2,selectlags =c("Fixed")))
```

Comment: you can change type=drift /none/trend.